# Listing all assignment categories for all classes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

Is it possible to list all assignment categories in use in a school, without having to query every class one by one? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-list-categories?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) seems to prove it's not possible, but is there a trick?

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't have a single endpoint that supports that right now. We support categories at a class level only.

Comment: This is useful. But could you quote a source, or make known any special affiliation you might have to relate this information to us in this manner.

Comment: With the .NET SDK, the EducationClass class has an AssignmentCategories property. Can I expand that property, or do I need to call the dedicated endpoint?